# Firebase Auth showing a Network or Timeout Error on Login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created an app which uses `firebase` as backend service. It was working fine until today. I am unable to login it is showing me an exception during login that says **" Error Occurred A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."**

This is my code for login which i think is alright:

```
  login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (((GlobalApp) getApplication()).isNetworkConnected()){
                if (validateinput()){
                    Loadingdialog.setTitle("Retrieving User");
                    Loadingdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    Loadingdialog.setCancelable(false);
                    Loadingdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    Loadingdialog.show();

                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailfield.getText().toString(),passfield.getText().toString())
                            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                       // saveuserToken();
                                        getUserDataFromDb();

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Loadingdialog.dismiss();
                                        Log.d("ErrorTag", "Error Occured " +task.getException().getMessage());
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }

            }else {
                // SHow Network error

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(findViewById(R.id.splashscreen),"Network Not Available", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                snackbar.show();

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Either You are not connected to Internet or u have not given INTERNET Permission in MANIFEST FILE  of Android.

Comment: i am connected to internet and given permission also

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```